# Structure about the Mach_O File

Tags: ios, decompiler, ida, mach-o

Hi guys who knows the align field is what?I use ida pro to destruct this file but interrupted at the __text section its maybe the developer had do someting into this macho file. like edit the offset field to avoid the developer decomplier this file.
[This Image is i use the otool command to decode the struct of this unix mach_o file (Click to see)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIVqO.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `align` field specifies the alignment required by the section. The base address of the segment must be a multiple of this the number you see (128 in your example).

The section alignment is computed to be the maximum of the alignments of all atoms in the section, in [`OutputFile::updateLINKEDITAddresses(ld::Internal& state)`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/ld64/ld64-264.3.102/src/ld/OutputFile.cpp).

Comment: Thanks for your link and answer